# Solve $\frac{7}{x+\sqrt{x+5}}+\frac{7}{x-\sqrt{x+5}}=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, radical-equations

Solve the equation: $$\dfrac{7}{x+\sqrt{x+5}}+\dfrac{7}{x-\sqrt{x+5}}=8.$$ I am not sure how to approach the problem. Should we first determine the domain? I think we can also check for every value we get for $x$ if the expression is defined, or not. The answers are $x=-\dfrac{5}{4}$ and $x=4.$ The numerators are equal and we also have resemblance in the denomitators. I am not sure how to use that. Thank you in advance! Happy holidays!

Comment: Think about getting both fractions in one bigger fraction, then it will simplify a lot.

Comment: I suggest rationalizing the denominators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{7}{x+\sqrt{x+5}}+\dfrac{7}{x-\sqrt{x+5}} = \frac{7(x-\sqrt{x+5})}{x^2-x-5} +\frac{7(x+\sqrt{x+5})}{x^2-x-5} \\ = \frac{14x}{x^2-x-5}$$ So the equation is equivalent to $$\frac{14x}{x^2-x-5} =8 \\ 14x =8x^2-8x-40 \\ 8x^2-22x-40=0$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Should I substitute in $\dfrac{14x}{x^2-x-5}=8$ to see if the expression is defined? Is it enough just to substitute in the original equation? I mean are we sure if the original equation is defined, then the mentioned by me is also defined?

Comment: @nicoledobreva If the very first expression is defined, then so are the rest. Plugging in the 2 roots in the original expression should suffice.

Comment: But why is that? Can you explain it to me, because I am not sure I understand it? I mean why "if the very first expression is defined, then so are the rest"?

Comment: Because at each step we are saying “if this is true, then <new equation> has to be true.”

Comment: Okay! I am still not sure I understand it, but I am trying. :)

Comment: Think of when an expression won’t be defined. Now if there’s some discrepancy in a middle step, wouldn’t the step before it also have the same discrepancy?

Comment: Can I ask what's a "discrepancy"? English is not my native language, and I am not really good with math words.

Comment: In this context, I mean something that would make an expression undefined.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\frac{7}{x + \sqrt{x+5}} + \frac{7}{x - \sqrt{x + 5}} = 8 & \Rightarrow \frac{14x}{x^{2} - x - 5} = 8\\\\
& \Rightarrow 8x^{2} - 22x - 40 = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow 4x^{2} - 11x - 20 = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow \left(x = - \frac{5}{4}\right)\vee(x = 4) 
\end{align*}

Substituting in the original equation, we conclude that they are solutions indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\frac{7}{x+\sqrt{x+5}}+\frac{7}{x-\sqrt{x+5}}=\frac{14x}{x^2-x-5}$$